# How to improve this algorithm to use three loops only?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, typescript

I want to print all four digit numbers in format ABCD such that A+B = C+D (known as “happy numbers”) with three nested loops. Here is the original code:

```
for (let a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
    for (let b = 0; b <= 9; b++)
        for (let c = 0; c <= 9; c++)
            for (let d = 0; d <= 9; d++)
                if (a + b == c + d)
                    console.log('${a}${b}${c}${d}');
```

and I tried to do it like that:

```
for (let a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
    for (let b = 0; b <= 9; b++)
        for (let c = 0,d=0; c <= 9,d <= 9; c++,d++)
            if (a + b == c + d)
                console.log('${a}${b}${c}${d}');
```

But the console doesn't print all the “happy numbers”. The first one goes like: 9687, 9696, 9779 and the second : 7144, 7355. Where is my mistake?

Comment: This is because the last loop is completely different from the original loops. It doesn't attempt different values of d for a given value of c. If 'c' fails for first time then d is also incremented, instead of trying a different d.

Comment: *"...with three nested loops"* ***Why?*** Four loops is the simple and correct way. You may be able to shoe-horn a three- or two- or even one-loop solution, but why?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Some new programmers tend to think that a 3 level nested loop is O(n^3) and 4 is O(n^4). Maybe that's why

Comment: Well, the thing _could_ be improved somewhat in terms of complexity. Right now it'd try assigning 0-9 to _each_ letter whereas we know for sure that if they all get assigned the same number (e.g., all are `1`) or are mirrored (e.g., `a=c=1`, `b=d=2`) then the sums would implicitly be the same, so all similar situations with repeating one or two repeating numbers on both sides can be pruned. We can also definitely conclude that if there is only _one_ repeat number on both sides (`a=c=1`, `b=2`, `d=3`) the sums won't be the same. What's left is different numbers for each letter - solve for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
    for (let b = 0; b <= 9; b++)
        for (let c = 0; c <= 9; c++) {
            const d = a + b - c;
            if (d >= 0 && d <= 9) console.log(`${a}${b}${c}${d}`);
        }
```

`d` is unique once you have `a`, `b`, and `c`, so you just need to calculate it.

Comment: The inner loop could be better if `c<=9` is replaced with `c<=a+b`. Then you don't need to check if d is positive and you skip some iterations when c is bigger than a+b

Comment: I think c should be c <a+b , because a+b could be 9+9 and numbers like 99108 occur

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here :

```
for (let c = 0,d=0; c <= 9,d <= 9; c++,d++)
```

Using this code, c and d will increment in the same time. So the second of your code will only print the happy numbers with the last 2 digits being the same (like 7144 and 7355).

I don't see why you want to use 3 loops tho... You could easily do this in one loop only :

```
for(let i = 1000; i < 10000; i++)
{
   if(/* test if i is happy here */)
        console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I use while loops instead or?

Comment: What is the benefit of use only one loop? You still have the same number of iterations (10000), and you probably need to do some divisions using one loop to test if the number is happy in each iteration.

Comment: Only one loop o.o Thank you. I'm quite new. This helped me a lot. Thank you everyone

Comment: @David No benefit really, I just could'nt see the benefits of trying to use 3 instead of 4 so I tried to make a point...

Answer (score 0):

in one loop.....

```
for (int i=1001;i<=9999;i++){
if(i/1000+(i/100)%10 == (i/10)%10+i%10)System.out.println("happy Number"+i);
    }
```

if you insist on 3 loops :

```
    String s1;
    Set<String> s=new TreeSet();
    for( int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
       s1=null;
        s1=""+i;
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
           String tempj=s1;
            s1=s1+j;
            for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
            {
                String tempk=s1;
            s1=s1+k;
            int temp=i+j-k;
            s1=s1+temp;
            if(temp<10)
            s.add(s1);
            s1=tempk;
            }
          s1=tempj;  
        }

    }

    for(String i:s )
    System.out.println(i+);
```